# Divisibiltiy of the order of elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, divisibility

Let $G$ be a finite group and ket $y \in G$.

How many elements $x \in G$ are there such that the order of $y$ is divisible by the order of $x$

Comment: It depends on each group !! Each group has a different case.

Comment: Let G be a dihedral group. So for y∈G.

How many elements x∈G are there such that the order of y is divisible by the order of x